# Apache Velocity html template: Problems with \n \t \r characters

Tags: html, google-chrome, velocity

I'm using HTML templates with Apache Velocity.
This is the dummy html template I'm using:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var dummyVar = "${dummyVar}";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            document.write(dummyVar);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the Java code I'm using:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dummy_rest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getProgrammesCatalog(){
    Map<String, Object> model = null;
    String html_text = null;    
    model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("dummyVar", "dummyValue");
    html_text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine,
            "dummy.html", "UTF-8", model);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    ResponseEntity<String> re = new ResponseEntity<>(html_text, headers, HttpStatus.OK); 
    return re;
}
```

So when I access to the address where the rest service is, this is the error message shown in the Chrome Developer Tools console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

It is pointing to the first (and unique) line of the code, which is showed like the following in the Chrome Developer Tools source:

```
"<html>\r\n\t<head>\r\n\t\t<script>\r\n\t\t\tvar dummyVar = \"dummyValue\";\r\n\t\t</script>\r\n\t</head>\r\n\t<body>\r\n\t\t<script>\r\n\t\t\tdocument.write(dummyVar);\r\n\t\t</script>\r\n\t</body>\r\n</html>"
```

And finally, what the browser is rendering is:

> "\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\r\n"

Even If I remove every \n character by searching for the regular expression, the error stays in. The file encoding is set to UTF-8. I've also tried to set it to UTF-8 without BOM.
Chrome browser should skip those characters (\t, \n, \r, ") instead of take them as tokens, but It does not.

However, the problem does not seem to be in Chrome browser (I've also tried it on Mozilla with the same result), but in the way Apache Velocity is parsing the template.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

The best approach I was able to get was to manually remove every character **"\n", "\r", "\t"** and **"""** (double quote).
So, just after

```
html_text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine,
                "dummy.html", "UTF-8", model);
```

I've added the following sentence:

```
html_text = html_text.replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "").replace("\r", "");
```

It is not a good solution at all. So, if anyone knows how to solve it, please let me now.